# What are <required> and <rtexprvalue> used for?

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, custom-tag

I was working on custom tag libraries and I was confused how the `<required>` and `<rtexprvalue>` tags are used in the TLD file to define a custom tag attribute.

1. What are these tags?
2. What should we write in-between them?
3. What behavior do we get after writing these tags?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnama.html#bnamh

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`required` quite simply implies what it says. The attribute is required or mandatory.

`rtexprvalue` means Runtime Expression Value. It means the attribute can support scriptlet values.

`elexprvalue` means it can support EL (expression language) values.

So, if you have `requiredattr` defined as both `required=true` and `rtexprvalue=true` and `elattribute` is defined as `elexprvalue=true`, you can write as follows:

```
<myprefix:mytag requiredattr="<%=baz.getId()%>" elattribute="${foo.bar}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will re-refer to the code once again and try it out!

can you tell me what will happen if i make rtexprvalue false??

What should i type in tag-lib file in between <rtexprvalue > tag ??

Comment: Generally `rtexprvalue` and `elexprvalue` are only made false when you don't want users of your taglib providing a runtime value. I have seen the `id` attributes being declared as `false` in some tag libraries.

Comment: Just to mention. With `rtexprvalue=true`, some implementations allow the concatenation, e.g. `requiredattr="<%=xxxx%>yyy"` , some others do not.

Answer (score 11):

The `<rtexprvalue>` element defined in a TLD captures the dynamic behavior of an attribute. The
value can be either true or false. A false value in the dynamic column means that
only a static string value can be specified for the attribute. A true value means that a
request-time attribute value can be specified. As defined in the JSP specification, a
“request-time attribute value” can be either a Java expression, an EL expression, or a
value set by a `<jsp:attribute>`.

The `<required>` element defines if the nesting attribute is required or optional. If not present then the default is "false", i.e the attribute is optional.