# Accepting variables in custom tags

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

How do I manage to pass a variable in a custom tag?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/lib/tags/customTag.tld" prefix="ct" %>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="2">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${i}" /></td>
            <td><ct:user par="1" num="${i}" /></td>
            <td><ct:user par="2" num="${i}" /></td>
        </tr>

    </c:forEach>
```

I am not able to pass ${i} into the *num* parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enable it in your tag definition file (*.tld):

see:  [What are <required> and <rtexprvalue> used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787582/what-are-required-and-rtexprvalue-used-for)